# C++ programm stops without a reason on a random position

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

I am working on a C++ program which should transfer a 2D image of a flame's intensity into a 3D model. The program is mainly working with multiple matrix-operations which I all realised using pointers (I know, I could use vectors though).
After the Input of the textfile, the mirroring and smoothing of the data values, there comes a correction calculation for each line of the image. At the beginning of the function for this calculation, the program stops on a random position but in the for-loop declaring the y_values-vector.

Here is the code-fragment:

```
void CorrectionCalculation(Matrix Matrix_To_Calculate, int n_values, int polynomial_degree, int n_rows)
{
    for (int h = 0; h < n_rows; h++)
    {
        //Initialising and declaration of the y_values-vector, which is the copy of each matrix-line. This line is used for the correction-calculation.
        double* y_values = new double(n_values);
        for (int i = 0; i < n_values; i++)
        {
            y_values[i] = Matrix_To_Calculate[h][i];
        }

        //Initialisiing and declaration of the x-values (from 0 to Spiegelachse with stepwidth 1, because of the single Pixels)
        double* x_values = new double(n_values);
        for (int i = 0; i < n_values; i++)
        {
            x_values[i] = i;
        }
```

When calculating a single line, the program worked fine. But when I added some code to calculate the whole image, the program stops.

Comment: `double* y_values = new double(n_values);` This won't make an array, but a single double element. How does the program behave after this correction (there are two of these)?

Comment: "Without a reason". Yep, your program is perfect, what were the designers of C++ thinking.

Comment: You are right, I should have written "without an obvious reason (for me and at the moment)". The initialization of y_values and x_values was the only happening where I forgot to use [] instead of (). Quite annoying not to figure out that failure, but it seems I stood on the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allocating an array of values, but a single element.
Instead of:

```
double* y_values = new double(n_values);
// ...
double* x_values = new double(n_values);
```

Change it to

```
double* y_values = new double[n_values];
//...
double* x_values = new double[n_values];
```

You should use a [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) of doubles rather than array new.  That way the memory will be automatically deleted when its no longer needed.  E.g.:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<double> y_values(y_values);
```

You're also [hiding variables](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/DCL01-CPP.+Do+not+reuse+variable+names+in+subscopes) by using variable names the same as the parameters.  This can lead to confusion and subtle bugs in code where you're not quite sure which variable is being changed.

Comment: seems like this was the error for the program stops working at this position.... quite annoying ;). Thank you very much. I also had to write this format on the initalization of x_values. Nevertheless it still stops... trying to figuere out the error now.

Comment: "consider using a vector" is by far not strong enough. Unless you are experienced and really know what you're doing, there is no reason to use the array new. I don't remember legitimately using it in ten years of C++ programming.

Comment: Okay I will use vectors. I just used arrays because we have been thought to do so - I think it mainly was because of understanding C++. Thanks for the support.